# Selectors - Finding second link of the section followed by section with text contains

Tags: selenium, xpath

I'm trying to find the second link of the section followed by the section with text "Contact"
In my case it should be this element: Tsukune (minced chicken patties)

```
        </section>
        <aside>
            <section class="popular-recipes">
                <h2>Popular Recipes</h2>
                <a href="">Yakitori (grilled chicken)</a>
                <a href="">Tsukune (minced chicken patties)</a>
                <a href="">Okonomiyaki (savory pancakes)</a>
                <a href="">Mizutaki (chicken stew)</a>
            </section>
            <section class="contact-details">
                <h2>Contact</h2>
                <p>Yoko's Kitchen<br>
```

I tried so many ways but without success

//*[contains(text(),'Contact')]//following-sibling::*[contains(text(),'Tsukune')]

/section/h2[.="Contact"]/following-sibling::text()[1]

Answer (score 0):

The following selector should work:

```
//*[contains(text(),'Contact')]//ancestor::section//preceding-sibling::section//*[contains(text(), 'Tsukune')]
```

First, we find the `Contact` element, go to its parent element - `section`. Then we find `section` which is a preceding sibling of the `section` and then - we find the element with `Tsukune` element

Answer (score 0):

If you want to select "Tsukune (minced chicken patties)", it's better to use:

```
//*[@class="popular-recipes"]//a[contains(text(), 'Tsukune')]
```

as this will have better performance than navigating using the parent, ancestor, sibling, etc.